# Iterating over a vector in C++ and changing the values dynamically

Tags: c++, vector

I am writing a c++ method that takes a vector vec of type T and returns a "delta" vector, i.e. vector with element vec(i)-vec(i-1) at position i, i>0 /I set the element at 0 to be the same as the one at 1/.

To do this, I firstly copy the vector vec and then iterate in this way:

```
template<class T>
vector<T> delta(vector<T> vec){
    vector<T> result(vec);
    for (typename vector<T>::iterator i = result.end(); i >= result.begin()+1; i--)
        {
            *i = *i - *(std::prev(i));
        }

    result.at(0) = result.at(1);
    return (result);
}
```

There seems to be some problem with the line

```
*i = *i - *(std::prev(i));
```

which I don't understand. If I change it to *i = *i - 1 it works fine. The other problem is that the program just fails without showing me errors (it pops a window with "main.exe has stopped working". I am using CLion IDE.

P.S. From the main I am passing an initialized vector with double values.

Comment: And what does your debugger tell you?

Comment: warning: Heap block at 003EAF20 modified at 003EB258 past requested size of 330

Comment: Your program is invalid. You cannot dereference an `.end()` iterator.

Comment: @n.m But when I change to *i = *i -1 it works. In a way this is dereferencing the i, which is initialized as .end()?

Comment: Sometimes the symptoms of undefined behaviour are that it appears to work. You still must not dereference a past-the-end iterator though, so stop doing that.

Comment: Isn't that a restricted version of std::adjacent_difference that you are implementing?

Comment: Until now I thought that .end() points at the last initialized value of the vector and that is where my confusion came from.

Comment: @manni66 Actually, yes.. Didn't know this function either. Thank you.

Comment: You should probably also make your function handle the case where the input has fewer than two elements (currently you'll get undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is undefined behavior. When you set your iterator to result.end(), you are dereferencing an end iterator to your vector, which is essentially the area in memory directly after your vector. It is possible for different functions, like std::prev or the dereference operator, to handle this differently. To eliminate this behavior, try this loop:

```
for (typename std::vector<T>::iterator i = result.end()-1; i >= result.begin()+1; i--) {
         *i = *i - *(i-1);
}
```

This loop simply starts at the last valid position in the vector (the end iterator -1).

Comment: Now I got it! Thank you! Until now I thought that .end() points at the last initialized value of the vector and that is where my confusion came from.

Comment: IMHO when iterating in reverse order it would be better to use a `reverse_iterator`, e.g. `for (auto i = result.rbegin(); i != result.rend() - 1; ++i) { *i = *i - *std::next(i); }`

Comment: @JonathanWakely you probably mean *(i+1) = *(i+1)-*i because this is not backwards difference as I want it to be. And in this case we should end at result.rend() - 2.

Comment: @Veliko no I meant what I wrote. When using a `reverse_iterator` the previous element in the container is the next position in the iterator traversal order.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I somehow missed the "reverse_iterator" part in your previous comment. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: The `reverse_iterator` part was the whole point of the comment! :-)